# Show close reason when reviewing reopen votes?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

While reviewing the Reopen Votes queue, the close reason for a question is not shown. It would be useful to see the reason why a question is closed when determining whether that close reason is still valid.

Comment: What do you mean by not shown? It is shown if you go to the revised view...

Comment: @hichris123 LOL... It is there, indeed.

Comment: Thanks @hichris123. It didn't even occur to me to look there, and I'm sure I'm not alone. I'd assume "revision" would show edits, not status changes.

Answer (score 8):

Feature you are looking for already exists. Thanks to @hicris123 for noting it. Questions are opened by default at Revision tab, but if you go on Question (revised) tab you will have the whole picture - close reason, comments...

[image]

I am leaving my original answer untouched, because that is IMHO how questions should be reviewed.

Comment: Interesting, didn't think to look under "Revision." It could maybe be surfaced better, but at least there's a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You should judge based on merit of the post. Even if one close reason no longer applies, some other might. And that is all that matters.

You are judging whether post deserves to be opened. And for that all you need is contained in the question itself. If the question is on topic based on current site guidelines about what constitutes on topic question then it deserves to be opened (unless it is a duplicate). If it is a bad and/or off topic question then leave it closed. Whether or not close reason still matches is not relevant.

The only close reason type where you can have on-topic question that still can be closed is duplicate, but in that case you can see that question has linked duplicate with it.

---

If you think you are really missing some information that original close vote might give you, then you are not competent enough to vote on that question either way. Simple as that. Just use **SKIP**. Leave that question for others that do know what they are doing in particular case.

Comment: OTOH, I can see how it might be useful if you're worried you missed some nuance of the original closure that would be revealed to you if you knew why the original voters came to their conclusion. As ever, context is key. Blind re-open voting is just pointless reversal of earlier hard work to determine the proper course of action, rather like a new political administration coming in and reversing all recent laws of the land without bothering to read the studies that originally led to their adoption. Now, I'm not saying people _have_ to vote to reopen but, if they do, they are doing it blindly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, doing it blindly is the problem. If you have any doubts then you should either skip the question or open the question outside the queue if you really need to. I don't see how original close reason might help if you are clueless.

Comment: That doesn't work if you _think_ you have all the information you need in front of you, but are actually missing a key piece of context. Putting that context right there on the review page will save you.... and everyone else.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, but I cannot imagine what key piece of context could close reason give you. If there is anything you could be missing is potential information in comments below the post that are also not visible in the queue. But you should not need even that.

Comment: Comments would be helpful too. Even something as simple as "this post has been discussed on meta" might lead you to realise that there was some big argument that got resolved, and an agreement was reached to close the question. You're about to reopen it without knowing any of that. You wouldn't go looking for that context before you know there _is_ any!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Point is there is no need for additional context. Regardless what it is. All you need is in the question. If you need more then you are either bad reviewer that does not know what is off/on topic for the site or you are not expert in the field question covers. I don't need other people guiding me in fields of my expertise, and in others I am not voting to reopen just because there is some code that looks like MCVE but I just don't know whether it actually is MCVE or not.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken, and I just explained why with an example. We are going around in circles.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yep, going in circles here... Post might be discussed in Meta is not an example. Give me real example of non-duplicate post that is on-topic and meta has decided that it should be left closed.

Comment: You're free to hunt down some examples if you need convincing. I reserve the right to leave you in ignorance ;) ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then I choose to be ignorant ;) I don't need any convincing. I am fine with what I believe in. If you want me to change my mind then you will have to provide some real hard evidence... I am not going to look for examples that would prove me wrong for one simple reason - I don't believe there are any. If I would believe otherwise I would agree with you in the first place.

Comment: I don't care whether you change your mind or not; I was just trying to be courteous by explaining why you are wrong and why I downvoted your answer. If you are not interested in learning, that is completely up to you and I support your decision. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been implemented a few weeks ago (I don't remember the exact date, and I don't see an entry in the [Recent feature changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/295232)). Below the prompt 'Should this question be reopened', it now shows the original close reason.

[image]