# Can we see details of "Not suitable for this site" close reason in the Reopen votes review interface?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Note: this could be duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336671/3995261), but that one was about the old interface and is no longer relevant.

In "reopen votes" review interface, some questions are marked as "Not suitable for this site":

> [image]

which is rather vague statement (which guidelines are not met?). Opening the question separately shows that they actually haven't provided enough details to reproduce/help debugging:

> [image]

These details are actually helpful for reviewing: once I know there were not enough details, I can focus on that and check if *that* was fixed (not formatting, wording, grammar or something else). So I wonder if we can have **these details directly in the review interface?** This would be especially helpful when **"This question is not reproducible or was caused by typos"**: once I know that, there's not much to review. Current behavior makes me open the question in a new tab each time when I see "Not suitable for this site".

Comment: They probably want you to have a fresh look at the whole question and not just to check whether one specific issue was solved (there may have been multiple issues). Example: A question closed for needing debugging details. The OP provides them and now it may appear fine at first glance and could be reopened, but a closer look reveals it was a typo and should stay closed.

Comment: I'm not sure the approach of checking whether the close reason has been fixed is sufficient. It may well be that a question has *multiple* issues, but is closed for one. Or fixing an early issue might reveal a new issue.

Comment: I agree with Jeanne and MisterMiyagi, you shouldn't be checking the reason for closure has been fixed, you should be checking if the question should be closed for _any_ reason. Reopening a post just to close it again for another reason is a waste of votes (except occasionally the case of reclosing as duplicate, although they can frequently be left closed for the wrong reason with a comment pointing to the intended target).

Comment: I agree with all of the comments... but that does not imply that it is relevant to hide information. You do review on good faith, then there should also be good faith that you are not going to be so easily misled by being able to see the truth.

Comment: Well, in general I understand and agree with the "It may well be that a question has multiple issues, but is closed for one" point; the main exception is the "not reproducible or was caused by typos" reason: if it's present, it should be the first thing to check since it's unlikely to be fixed anyway.